# How to use 'dialogflow' client library with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, dialogflow-es

I have a working Typescript codebase, running server-side in NodeJS v10.18.0 and I am trying to integrate the ['dialogflow' client library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow) into it.

Note that this is NOT the dialogflow webhook/fulfilment API. It's the client API.

But I can't get 'dialogflow' to 'import' with Typescript, any which way, even though [@types/dialogflow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/dialogflow) claims that the package is properly typed already.

**Basic test case:**

Start in an empty folder somewhere, then:

```
$ npm init     # Accept all defaults
$ tsc --init
$ npm install --save dialogflow @types/node
```

Now create `index.ts` containing:

```
import * as df from 'dialogflow'
```

You can try other import styles. They all hit the same problem.

Then try:

```
$ tsc
```

It complains with:

```
index.ts:1:29 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'dialogflow'.
```

**What gives? What am I doing wrong?**

(I am not an expert on module typing with Typescript)

**Is dialogflow typed for Typescript or not?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently only option is to use deprecated version.

Install

```
npm i -D @types/dialogflow@0.11.0
```

Code

```
import * as df from 'dialogflow';
const config = { ... };
const sessionClient = new df.SessionsClient(config);
```

Refer [this comment](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/39627#issuecomment-553987606). Hope the official library will be fixed soon.

Note following option does not work, as it don't have correct type definitions.

```
import * as dialogflow from 'dialogflow/protos/protos'
```

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow for Node.js had been changed the package name to `@google-cloud/dialogflow` that included TypeScript definition. https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow

Comment: Does it have workable typings yet? I can find no workable typescript examples online, nor find any usable types in any obvious place in the package. Have you had any more luck @tonkla?

Comment: @spechter: Me neither, I cannot find any usable example. They mention about it but they didn't give any example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example with dialogflow 1.2.0:

```
import * as dialogflow from 'dialogflow';
import config = require('../src/config/common.conf');

async function runSample(text: string, language: string, sessionId: string): Promise<CustomType> {
  const projectId = config.gcp.dialogflow.projectId;
  const credentials = {
    credentials: {
      private_key: config.gcp.dialogflow.privateKey,
      client_email: config.gcp.dialogflow.clientEmail,
    },
  };

  const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials);
  const sessionPath = sessionClient.sessionPath(projectId, sessionId);
  const request = {
    session: sessionPath,
    queryInput: {
      text: {
        text: text.slice(0, 255),
        languageCode: language,
      },
    },
  };

  const [response]: dialogflow.DetectIntentResponse[] = await sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
  return transformDialogFlowResponse(response);

}
```